# How can i add AUTOSHIP feature in Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Please help me out how to add autoship in wordpress...
I have user subscription plans on my website so i need to ship user subscribed items on the basis of their plans..so how to manage this and keep track of everything..

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

```
Try below plugins. May those plugins useful for your task.
**-> woocommerce-subscriptions**
**-> woocommerce-memberships**

In this 2 plugins you need to add proper setting.
Follow this link to for " Woocommerce-subscription ": https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/
```